# How to open a .jar written with jdk 12

Tags: java, jar, java-12

I'm writing a java application using JDK 12.
From Java 11, Oracle doesn't provide any JRE.
So, JDK 11 and JDK 12 don't have Java Runtime Envirnoment.

How can i execute jar written using jdk 11 or jdk 12?

I tried using jre 8 and it works.

How is possible open jar file written using jdk 12 with jre 8?
I read on Internet that from Java 11, jar files have a little jre inside.
But i need java 8 anyway for open them?

Answer (score 2):

Both Java 11 and Java 12 JDKs have all you need to run a packaged jar file. Assuming that your installation is correct and you have the correct environmental variables in place, simply doing:

`java -jar <jar_file>`

should work properly for you. Granted JDKs nowadays do not have a specific jre folder as it was in the past, but that does not mean that they do not provide anything needed for you to run a java application. Just have a look at the bin folder for more.

Now regarding your second question. Is it possible to run a java application that has been compiled against a newer version using an older jre. Well the answer is it depends. Normally running bytecode produced from a newer jdk against an older jre will result in class compatibility errors. This can be circumvented by compiling your application in compatibility mode (most likely your case).

So to sum up. Go ahead and install the correct Java version (ideally the one you develop with and planning to deploy on). Set up your environment correctly and you'll have no problem running anything.

Comment: So if i deploy a Java application written in Java 12, how can i execute It on costumer's computer if jre 12 doesn't exist? Should i install jdk on costumer's computer?

Comment: I still fail to understand what do you mean that no jre exists.  AdoptOpenJDK offers pre bundled jres https://adoptopenjdk.net/archive.html?variant=openjdk12&jvmVariant=hotspot. I think you're failing to understand simple concepts such as what a jdk and what a jre is and how you can find one.

Comment: @GaetanodeGennaro if you insist on retrieving the implementation from Oracle then, yes, just install a JDK. That’s what I’m doing since…I don’t know, JDK1.4, as Sun’s JRE bundles did not contain the faster server mode JVM for some distributions and some JREs contained crapware like the Ask toolbar. So JDK was the better choice for a long time already. It contains some additional developer tools, which not every user will need, but well, there are tons of stuff not every user needs.

Comment: @GaetanodeGennaro Also, you can package your application with an embedded runtime using `jlink` (if your code is modular). You'll also be able to create native executables/installers using `jpackage` (slated for Java 13, currently early-access).